A problem occurred configuring project ':mapbox_gl'
i just finished a prototype and when i run flutter build apk --release i get this error: (flutter 3.22.1) how am i supposed to fix it? thanks in advance:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':mapbox_gl'.


Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mapbox_gl' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mapbox_gl' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

ps: that's my android\build.gradle:
`buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3' // Adjust if necessary
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven' }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
`

and this is my android\app\build.gradle:

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.testproject"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.testproject"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true // Enable multidex
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
   // implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:2.0.0"// Specify the Kotlin version
  //  implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven' }
}
flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

i updated the mapbox_gl dependency still same problem
